# Why does a Hamentash have three sides?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

All Hamentashen that I've seen have three sides and all Hamentashen have filling.

Why is that?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: [Also asked seriously.](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14555)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hamentashen comes from the words "Haman Tish" -- the Table of Haman in Yiddish.

Therefore, since there were three people by Haman's party they needed a three sided table (both Haman and Achashveirosh considered themselves to be the most important people in Persia and wouldn't want to sit with Esther).

The Hamentash represents the Table on which they (Haman,Esther and Achashveirosh) sat and the filling represents the food which they ate. (From where the custom to give a "[last meal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_meal)" came).

What food do royalty eat?

Caviar.

But there's an argument over what kind of Caviar did they eat, red caviar or black caviar.

So that's why there are two kinds of filling - poppy (representing *black* caviar) and jelly (representing *red* caviar).

Comment: why wouldn't they want to sit with Esther and how does the three sided table resolve this?

Comment: So. ... why don't we get caviar hamantaschen? :P

Answer (score 19):

Unfortunately, this is nothing more than a common misconception which stems from ignorance and from a lack of proper education in certain communities. Hamentashen **are not required** to have 3 sides. There's a famous derasha from the spelling of the word haman: just like a **מ** has 3 sides, a **ה** has two and a half, and a **ן** has one and a bit, so too a hamentashen: as long as it has one side and a bit of a second, it's permissible.

Comment: So it's a [**möbius**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip)tashen!

Comment: You might object: perhaps this just teaches us the proper way to eat a hamentash - it must start out with three sides, but then it gets reduced? The answer is that we would say so if the name had been מהן, with the letters in that order. Since the ה comes first, and you can't add on an extra half a side to the hamentash after it's baked, this demonstrates that indeed these are the acceptable shapes at the time it's made.

Comment: This _halacha_ is necessary to be taught, otherwise only the first bite would be considered to fulfill the _mitzva_. And while the ideal case might be that everyone should have his own _hamentash_, once we know that a _hamentash_ with a bite taken out of it is still _kosher_, we can infer that a _hamentash_ can be shared between multiple people and each of them will be _yotze_.

Answer (score 16):

#### Why does it have three sides?

If it had four sides it would need *tzitzis*! (I can't take any credit for this answer: it's older than I am.)

#### Why is it filled?

Consider [*Rus* 1:20–21](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2901.htm#20):

> אַל תִּקְרֶאנָה לִי נָעֳמִי קְרֶאןָ לִי מָרָא כִּי הֵמַר שקי לִי מְאֹד. אֲנִי מְלֵאָה הָלַכְתִּי וְרֵיקָם הֱשִׁיבַנִי ה׳

We see from there that that which might be expected to be filled but is in fact unfilled is bitter.

Hamentaschen, of course, are expected to be filled (ask anyone), so leaving them unfilled would make them bitter, and who wants to eat a bitter hamentasch?

Comment: would need or knead?

Comment: @ShmuelBrill, it would *need* _tzitzis_. Kneading _tzitzis_ is forbidden based on the _chashash_ that you may come to braid them into _chalos_, which is not the correct way of tying them.

Comment: @msh210 The [shulchan aruch](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=36) rules that something for your head would not be chayav in tzitzit, and we all know that ‏**אזנ**י המן are for your head.

Comment: @msh210: this is borne out by a pasuk in Koheles (4:12): והחוט המשולש לא במהרה ינתק. Al tikrei ינתק, ela יקנת - the strings on the triangular hamentash shall not be quickly braided (*kneyt*, in Yiddish).

Comment: You have trouble eating your hamentaschen without wearing them?