# "Silk-Screened" Sifrei Torah

Tags: sources-mekorot, technology, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, sefer-torah

What are the halachic issues with Silk-screened sifrei torah? I am interested in a summary of concise *halakhic* rulings of multiple authorities on the prohibition or permissibility of [HaRav Yitzchak Abadi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aRabbi_Yitzchak_Abadi.png)'s [innovation](http://kashrut.org/scrollproject/) of silk screen *sifrei torah*. Please provide piskei halacha, and I prefer that the *shitot ha-poskim* come from reputable sources.

(As always, CYLOR before you make any decisions.)

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but can you give a brief description of what silk screening is in the body of the question?

Comment: http://www.hakirah.org/Vol19Kleinhendler.pdf

Comment: here's a demonstration of how it works https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WvFED55xhv8

Answer (score 14):

Since no one has listed a summary of concise rulings, I will list R. Bleich's conclusion from his [Survey of Recent Halakhic Periodical Literature](http://www.traditiononline.org/news/article.cfm?id=104957). I have inserted the sources that he mentioned throughout the survey in brackets.

> The silk screen method is certainly subject to challenge on the basis of its inherent incompatibility with a number of considerations:
>
> 1. The position of **Bah [O''H 32:15]**, who maintains that each word must be vocalized before writing even when there is no chance of scribal
>      error;
> 2. The view of the authorities who maintain that each word must be copied from an existing text and that an error-free “master text” is
>      not sufficient for this purpose **[Bnei Yonah no. 271, Pilpul Arukh, p.
>      14a; Piskei Uzi'el, no. 31]**
> 3. The view of the authorities who maintain that multiple Divine Names cannot be sanctified even simultaneously **[Bnei Yonah 276:2; Divrei
>      Hamudot, Halakhot Ketanot, Hilkhot Sefer Torah 4:11; Ma’adanei Tom
>      Tov, Halakhot Ketanot, Hilkhot Sefer Torah 4:5; Eliyahu Rabbah 32:36;
>      Teshuvot Bet Shlomoh, Yoreh De’ah, II, no. 163; Teshuvot Dvar Shmu’el,
>      no. 76; Melekhet Shamayim, no. 5; Birkei Yosef Yoreh De’ah 276:3; Bet
>      Aharon, no. 12; Teshuvot Maharam Shik, Yoreh De’ah, no. 276; Kol
>      Ya’akov, Yoreh De’ah 274:4; R. Yitzchak Dov Bamberger, Melekhet
>      Shamayim, Binah 9:3; and Hazon Ish, Orah Hayyim 6:13, Yehaveh Da'at,
>      VI, no. 57; ; Teshuvot Helek Levi O''H, no. 26]**
> 4. **Iggeret Mosheh’s view [O''H, IV, no. 40 sec. 10]** that any method in which *sirtut* serves no purpose is disqualified;
> 5. The view of **Teshuvot Zera Avraham [Y''D 117], She’ilat David [no. 7 sec. 2], Da’at Kohen [no. 160] and Piskei Uzi’el [no. 31]** that the
>      printing press is not acceptable because “it is not in the manner o f
>      writing.”
> 6. The kabbalistic view expressed by **Ari [Bnei Yonah, Pilpul Arukh, no. 271, p. 15a]** regarding the particular form of writing that governs
>      the manner in which the writing of each letter is begun.
>
>    Nevertheless, a competent rabbinic decisor might, with justification, conclude that those are minority views and consequently rely upon the weight of authority in ignoring such concerns. The crucial consideration is whether or not the silk screen method
>      constitutes either “spilling” or “dripping” and hence is ruled invalid
>      by the **Palestinian Talmud [Gittin 2:3 and Shabbat 12:4]**. Since the
>      validity of Torah scrolls, tefillin and mezuzot is a matter of
>      biblical law, any doubt, if the there is indeed such doubt, must be
>      resolved in the negative. Thus, it would be necessary either to adduce
>      strong precedent in support of the validity of a method similar to the
>      silk screen process or to advance a compelling logical distinction
>      between that method and the processes described by the Palestinian
>      Talmud. In this writers opinion, the requisite demonstration has not
>      been forthcoming.

In addition, R. Bleich notes the reaction of contemporary rabbinic authorities, who have overwhelmingly prohibited the silk screen method and noted that Torah scrolls and ST'aM that were silk screened are unfit for use. In the form of letters signed and occasional responsa released, which were published in Yated Ne’eman, 24 Kislev 5763; 16 Kislev 5763; Yated Ne’eman, Parashat Mikez 5763, and an earlier letter dated Tammuz 5762.

**The signatories prohibiting silk screen include**: R. Ovadia Yosef, R. Yosef Shalom Eliashiv, R Samuel ha-Levi Woszner, R. Nissim Karelitz, the members of the Bet Din of Jerusalem’s Edah ha-Haredit, R. Chaim Pinchas Scheinberg, and R Menachem Yehudah ha-Levi Gross [who wrote a detailed analysis explaining the prohibition in the Tammuz 5762 issue of *Or Torah*]. You can read a translation R. Wosner's letter [here](http://frumscams.blogspot.co.il/2013/05/bogus-mezuzos-tefilin-and-sifrei-torah.html).

Besides R. Abadi's responsum [[Or Yizhak, no. 53]](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1525&st=&pgnum=359&hilite=), the only published source that somewhat defends the silk screening process is an anonymous pamphlet called *Ha-Emet ve-ha-Shalom Ahevu*, who ultimately concedes that it shouldn't be done as R. Eliashiv has ruled against it.

### UPDATE:

[R. Abadi has responded](http://www.kashrut.org/forum/viewpost.asp?mid=5527) to the letters of Gedolim who prohibited silk screening, arguing that they didn't see the process, and claims that "Rav Scheinberg, Rav Tuvia Goldstein ZT"L who both saw the process and Rav Dovid Feinstein, who did not see it, among "others", said it is Kosher." [R. Abadi has also responded to R. Bleich's survey](http://www.kashrut.org/forum/viewpost.asp?mid=5439), in which he commends the thorough treatment and respect in the article. He notes that the "crucial consideration" of spilling does not happen in silk screening, and invites anyone to see the process to prove his case.

Since R. Bleich's article (published in 2003), several responsa have come out. As [sam pointed out](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17925/1865), R. Belsky has prohibited the practice in his *Sha'alos U'Teshuvos Shulchan Halevi*. R. Ovadia has also written about the grave sin of the silk screen method in *Chazon Ovadia Purim* (רנה), saying that nobody who uses a Torah scroll or ST'aM that was silk screened fulfills any mitzvah. The newest **Yalkut Yosef, in 691:15**, cites *Chazon Ovadia* in prohibiting the practice, adding that not only are they *passul b'dieved*, but also:

> והמברכים עליהם ברכתם ברכה לבטלה, והוא מכשול חמור מאד, שמכשיל את הרבים באיסור ברכה לבטלה ובביטול מצות מקרא מגילה.
>
> One who blesses on them [megillah] has said a blessing in vain, and this is a very serious stumbling block, thwarting the public through the prohibition of saying a blessing in vain and wasting the mitzvah of reading the megillah.

Comment: R' Belsky (cited above) 'somewhat defends the silk screening process'. His problem with silk-screened sifrei torah is that it would be easier to forge.

Comment: @ArielK: Thanks, I included that source in the update.

Comment: "there needs to be a law against footnotes that exceed in volume, say 10% of an article." LOL! I see he hasn't read much by R Bleich.

Answer (score 12):

[R. J.D. Bleich](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._David_Bleich) covered this topic in a recent [Survey of Recent Halakhic Periodical Literature](http://traditionarchive.org/news/originals/Volume%2037/No.%201/Survey%20of%20Recent.pdf). In the article he discusses a number of possible issues that have been raised with Silk-screen Sifrei Torah, but says that most of them are not so strong. He says there is one serious objection where the burden of proof falls on the innovators to show that it is OK:

The issue is the halacha in the gemara that says that the ink cannot be spilled or dripped. When the ink is pressed by a scribe, is that considered spilling/dripping and therefore is passul?

P.S.
A video of the process is available on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WvFED55xhv8).

Comment: In order to improve your answer, could you please add some of the specific issues that R. J.D. Bleich raises?

Comment: Rabbi Abadi preempts this argument and deals with it at length in the teshuva that I cited (and I would expect one to properly read the teshuva before posing difficulties with its final outcome). R. Bleich is certainly entitled to disagree; my point is mainly to clarify that the issue presented in this answer is not something R. Abadi hasn't considered.

Comment: OK, but R. Bleich feels that R. Abadi's argument is not convincing enough, so they do not have enough proof to justify an entirely new practice.

Comment: @DovF Thank you for pointing that out. Perhaps if you could summarize some of the main points of the Teshuva in your answer it would better help people understand the machloket.

Comment: @DoubleAA It is a very long and exhaustive teshuva. That being said I really do not know the sugya and would not be able to properly summarize it at this time. (And again - this should go unsaid - I would expect anyone who wishes to debate the fine points of this ruling to first go through the entire teshuva very well. As an aside, from personal knowledge I know that the chabura in BMG that recently studied this sugya was generally unimpressed with the opposing arguments.)

Comment: @DovF Fair enough. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17907/silk-screened-sifrei-torah/17913#comment42150_17908

Answer (score 8):

Rav Belsky, on page 9 of *Shulchan Halevi* (English version), explains that while theoretically silk-screening could be kosher for writing Stam, there are some issues which can come up. He mentions that forgeries would increase, and there there could be a problem of kesidran ("written in order," which Teffilin and Mezuzah require).

Then he brings an issue with sirtut (line indents under the letters to help guide the sofer to keep the letters in a straight line) - that Mezuzah needs it,  and even according to many shittos a sefer Torah needs it. It could be a problem  according to Rabbi Akiva Eiger in *Shailos and Tshuvos* Siman 50.

He ends with the famous idea "chadasha assur min HaTorah" (anything new is forbidden). To revolutionize the way a mitzvah is to be performed or prepared, the initiative has to come from the Gedolei Hador, not from any single individual.

It is best to see it inside since I did not fully elaborate on the topic.

Comment: [Chodosh actually _is_ assur min haTorah](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12852/759) but no one ever cares to use that phrase the way it was originally meant to be used.

Comment: Are you suggesting this change is not coming from Gedolei Yisrael?

Comment: @doubleaa, if I'm not mistaken, the innovator of the term in its, *ahem*, new usage, is the Ch"S, who certainly knew of its "original" meaning, and was making a play on words.

Comment: @SethJ AFAIK you are correct. I'm not complaining that he made a pun; only that no one gets that it is a pun.

Comment: You don't think R' Belsky gets that it was a pun? I think that, although it was a pun, the Ch"S meant it very seriously, as do the Gedolim who have followed.

Comment: @DoubleAA I am not saying anything just sourcing what I read.

Comment: Average Yoseles may take it seriously never realizing it was a pun, though.

Comment: @sam Sorry I wasn't trying to accuse you of anything. I'm just surprised because of all the 'modern innovations' with halacha, this one actually was started and continues to be led only by well meaning Orthodox frum Rabbis. So I'm not sure why R Belsky would complain about the idea's source.

Comment: Pun or no pun the idea of the Chasam Sofer was very clear we do not veer away from the way things were done for hundred years even if it is mutar.

Comment: Even Rav Belsky agreed that it could be done ,but since this is how its been done for years it takes the Gedolei Hador to change it.

Comment: @sam Good thing the project was started and is being led by a Gadol HaDor.

Comment: @SethJ Obviously R Belsky knew it was a pun. And obviously they are making a certain hashkafic statement. But I think they sometimes overlook the fact that most people don't know the history behind it, and this particular phraseology leads to the disconception that there is some technical issur or something. Those that take this position are certainly entitled to do so, but it should be known what the position is and what it isn't.

Comment: @SethJ This wasn't supposed to become a hashkafa argument. I was really just complaining that almost no one has any idea what Chadash is even though it's an explicit pasuk and applies according to a whole lot of rishonim.

Comment: @DoubleAA I am in no way arguing one way or the other they are both Torah giants and I am no one to agree or disagree.

Answer (score 4):

Rav Abadi's original teshuva can be found [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1525&st=&pgnum=359&hilite=).

Comment: I am looking for rulings from multiple authorities.

Comment: @AdamMosheh One is part of multiple.

Comment: NOTE If anyone has learned through this teshuva before please edit in a summary of his main points.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a bunch of essays that explain the potential problems. Also In Minchas Asher (Rav. A. Weiss Shu"t Minchas Asher Y.D. 53) there is a teshuvah about this and he also does not hold of it.
see [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=13068&st=&pgnum=70&hilite=), [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42891&st=&pgnum=257&hilite=) [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50515&st=&pgnum=64&hilite=) , and [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=13608&st=&pgnum=48&hilite=)

Comment: see also http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50515&st=&pgnum=64&hilite=
http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=13608&st=&pgnum=48&hilite=