# Why cant a Sefer torah be written by a machine

Tags: kashrut-kosher, sefer-torah, torah-writing

It seems that Sefer toras can't be used for torah readings/alias(since nobody uses them for it and the amazing facts and feats book mentions a machine made Sefer can't be used. But Why cant a Sefer torah be written by a machine? If it's about lishma my pressing the start button should be good enough no?

Comment: Could pushing a button be construed as Derekh Ketiva? Writing with you left hand (if you are a righty) is also invalid

Comment: @Double AA That's a good point though I could hear a argument that pushing a button with your right hand works.

Comment: See this lengthy exposition by R. Yitzchak Abadi ([no. 4](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1525&st=&pgnum=365)) which particularly relates to the [silk-screen process](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17907).

Comment: The Taz discusses using the a printing press,this is a very big discussion,if you can get your hands on a Yesodei Yeshurun on weekday davening he brings all opinions regarding this

Comment: Rav Abaidis way is a bit diff than a printing press since by his you push the ink through the silk sceeen,by a printing press the letters are formed already

Comment: I will try and post the Yesodei Yeshurun text later

Comment: @sam https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48072/759

Comment: Hakirah has an article on the topic [here](http://www.hakirah.org/Vol19Kleinhendler.pdf) which I found excellent

Answer (score 2):

[Rambam](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%96%D7%95%D7%96%D7%94_%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%99) list some things which would not give a Torah Scroll not a drop of sanctity and would be like a printed book:

If someone who wrote it is an [Apikores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epikoros) or any other type of prohibited person.
If someone wrote it without concentrating on Divine names.

> שכתבו אפיקורוס או כיוצא בו משאר פסולין
>
> שכתב האזכרות בלא כוונה

Computers seem to fall under that category.

> In Kerisos 19b it is explained: Machshava is when someone thinks to do something, kavana is when someone is doing something for X.
>
> -[Rogechover](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43922&st=&pgnum=278&hilite=)

You may have kavana with the button, but the computer doesn't.

Comment: "Computers seem to fall under that category" - I don't see how it fits the first category. A computer has no emotions (well, maybe "Alexa", Siri and that GPS woman do.) As for lack of concentration, would programming a computer to write the names in their proper position constitute *kavanah*? What about if one stopped the program just prior to the computer writing the name and then was there to witness the computer write the Divine names?

Comment: I was also thinking a computer is certainly not a human, so it can't be kosher or pasul to write @DanF

Comment: @shmuel my pen isn't human but its allowed to write. The point would be that the machine like a pen or the rest of my property is a extension of me

Comment: If we could extented someone’s hand why do try to be ‘yotze’ with writing a letter in the Torah, as apposed to having someone else do it. (Unless we de?...) @orion