# What is the Jewish tradition of writing Torah scroll?

Tags: mitzvah, sefer-torah

I am trying to learn more about the tradition of rewriting the Torah.

Torah Robot by Matthias Gommel was displayed at the Jewish Museum in Berlin which I visited in 2015. The robot walks across the paper scroll and pens the Hebrew letters with black ink. For this machine, it takes about 3 months to write The Five Books of Moses. I understand this is just an art installation to display the real Jewish tradition of rewriting the scrolls of the Torah.

Where could I find more information about this Jewish tradition? Is this duty explained in Torah or any other scripture?

Comment: Welcome to MY! Have you checked out Wikipedia? They have quite many good entries on Judaism related topics. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_mitzvah_to_write_a_Torah_scroll

Comment: https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Writing_a_Sefer_Torah https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48070/is-a-machine-written-sefer-torah-distinguishable-from-machine-matzos