# Can one write sta"m via a stencil?

Tags: tefilin, safrus, mezuzah, torah-writing

Say you wanted to write a tefillin, mezuzah, Torah, or any other sta"m venture. To make it easier for you, you created a stencil of the text that you can overlay on the klaf and fill in. You hope thereby to avoid mistakes and have the letters always perfect.

What are the halachic issues you may run into here? If it's OK in theory, must you fill in the letters as if the stencil weren't there (ie. follow "stroke order"), or could you simply fill the empty spaces with ink (in letter order, of course, if you're writing a tefillin/mezuzah). Are there any *halachic* authorities that speak to this?

I'm reminded of the [silk-screen Torahs](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17907/silk-screened-sifrei-torah), created similarly (rolling ink over a stencil, many words at once). Comparing with the problems raised in [one of the answers to that Mi Yodea question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/30209/4940), hand-writing one letter at a time with stencils seems to avoid the issues.

Comment: http://www.hakirah.org/Vol19Kleinhendler.pdf

Comment: This is discussed by signing a get in the gemoro and poskim.

Comment: @interested Thanks. I see some relevant material in Gittin 9b Tosafot/Rabbeinu Crescas. But even if it's OK there, gittin are more lenient than sta"m.

Comment: @magicker72 I wouldnt think that in this it would make a difference. It does say that one didnt want to teach how to write. He could write a shem holding four pens and it was all written at once. If you could use a stencil then anyone could do it.

Comment: @interested I don't understand your comment after the first sentence, sorry.

Comment: @magicker72 Do you know the gemoro in yuma about the sofer who didnt want to teach how to write

Comment: @interested Instead of asking, you could just point me to it please.

Comment: @magicker72  בן קמצר לא רצה ללמד על מעשה הכתב.  https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%90_%D7%92_%D7%99%D7%90  על מעשה הכתב - קושר ד' קולמוסים בד' אצבעותיו, וכותב שם בן ד' אותיות כאחת